# Using HTML array with C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, html, multi-select

I have a pure HTML (.html extension) page that posts to a .aspx page that I need to get the multiple selection from. In PHP, this is handled by simply adding the square brackets to the element name and treating it as an array.

```
<select name="select[]" multiple>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" />

<?php
foreach ($_REQUEST["check"] as $check) {
    // Processing code
}
?>
```

Is there similar functionality in C#? Or do I have to name every element special? I've been searching online, but everything says to use the `HtmlControls` or the `CheckBoxList` classes, which are unavailable because of it being static HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to add square brackets to name of the input. Just name it as you want:

```
<input type="text" name="textBoxes" />
<input type="text" name="textBoxes" />
```

Then simply use `GetValues()` in code behind:

```
string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("textBoxes");

foreach (var val in values) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked perfectly. I knew there had to be a way, but I'm still fairly new to C# so I wasn't sure what it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using static HTML, you will need to use Javascript to get the values that you want to then pass on to the aspx page

Comment: Why in the world would you pass it to JavaScript to send it to any other page? You just use the form submit and set action to the aspx page.